# NHibernate: storing / retrieving dates in / from Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have this simple object

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public virtual DateTime TimeStamp { get; }
}
```

I would like to know how to map a DateTime property sqlite using nhibernate,

Tried something like this

```
 mapping.Map(Reveal.Member<Something>("TimeStamp"))
            .Default(DateTime.UtcNow.Second.ToString())
            .Generated.Insert()
            .Not.Nullable();
```

When trying to do an insert

```
            session.Save(new SomeObject());
            tran.Commit();
```

I get this

> Input string '29' was not in the correct format.'
>   InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'Int32' to 'DateTime'.

Comment: Why are you using "int" as `CustomSqlType` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
mapping.Map(Reveal.Member<Something>("TimeStamp"))
            .CustomType<DateTime>()
            .CustomSqlType("datetime")
            .Default(DateTime.UtcNow.Second.ToString())
            .Generated.Insert()
            .Not.Nullable();
```